# Insert QuerySet results in a table in Django which have same fields

Tags: django

I have a QuerySet which will have the information from some x-table and now I want to insert these values into another table which have same fields as of x-table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If models `A` and `B` have the exact same fields, you can do something like this:

```
a_objects = A.objects.all()
# loop over objects
for a in a_objects:
    # convert a to dictionary
    a_dict = a.__dict__
    a_dict.pop('id')   # remove primary key from dict
    # create B model
    B.objects.create(**a_dict)
```

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382546/how-can-i-turn-django-model-objects-into-a-dictionary-and-still-have-their-forei) for other ways to convert a model to a dictionary.